# How would I set a limit so it would stop a loop at set amount by user?

Tags: java

//counter class used in OPP for with the demo code, it should work with the code supplied but the output is all wrong and the setLimit wont limit anything

```
public class CounterExtended {
    private int value;
    /**
     * Gets the current value of this counter.
     * 
     * @return the current value
     */
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Advances the value of this counter by 1.
     */
    public void count() {
        value = value + 1;
    }

    /**
     * Resets the value of this counter to 0.
     */
    public void reset() {
        value = 0;
    }

    public void setLimit(int maximum) {
        if (value >= maximum)
            System.out.printf("Limit of",maximum, "exceeded");
    }


    public void undo() {
        if (value>=0){
         value--;
        }

    }
}
```

and Democode

```
public class Demo {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                CounterExtended tally = new CounterExtended();
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
                        if (i > 7) {
                                tally.setLimit(6);
                        }
                        tally.count();
                        System.out.printf("After count %d, tally is %d\n", i,
                                        tally.getValue());
                }
                tally.undo();
                tally.undo();
                tally.count();
                System.out.printf("After 2 undo's and one count, tally is %d\n",
                                tally.getValue());

        }

}
```

AND OUTPUT SHOULD LOOK LIKE AFTER IT RUNS THE CODE ABOVE

```
After count 1, tally is 1
After count 2, tally is 2
After count 3, tally is 3
After count 4, tally is 4
After count 5, tally is 5 
Limit of 5 exceeded
After count 6, tally is 5 
Limit of 5 exceeded
After count 7, tally is 5 
After count 8, tally is 6 
Limit of 6 exceeded
After count 9, tally is 6
Limit of 6 exceeded
After count 10, tally is 6
After 2 undo's and one count, tally is 5
```

Comment: I see no such loop...

Comment: Where's the loop from your title question in the code?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/cNTurCnn this program should demo the code. This is suppose to teach us OOP but totally confused now.

Comment: the demo code is all correct I just had to create the code snippet above Counterextended.java

Comment: And one more thing Im new to formatting code on here and the top is cutoff

Comment: @Makoto mind looking again I would surely appreciate the help

Comment: Go ahead and edit that into your question.

Comment: Where do you set the value in your program?

Comment: @loki when you call the set limit function

Comment: setLimit is not setting anyvalue, it just checking for limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is obviously "a learning exercise" so hints only:

The problem you have been set is to figure out how to make your counter class behave as per the sample output when used by the supplied test harness.  Obviously (other readers take note!) changes to the test harness are not allowed.

- What does the output *imply* that `count()` *should* do in the event of an overflow.  (Hint: It should NOT stop the loop ...)
- What does the output *imply* that `getValue()` *should* return after an overflow?
- What extra state do you need to record in a `CounterExtended` instance to achieve that?
- Is the current instance field of a `CounterExtended` instance the best way to achieve that?  (Hint: No ... but you need to figure out *why* it is not.)

Comment: for number two we need another value??

Comment: @JDMshifter - refresh your browser.  Your comments no longer line up.

Comment: count() is just the increment and getValue() just returns the current value. are you saying I need another value?

Comment: @JDMshifter - I am saying that you need to understand what the results you are seeing (in the output) imply; i.e. how those methods are supposed to behave, and what you need to store.  Read the output and the test harness code **carefully** and make your own judgements.

Comment: (I am deliberately not answering your question ... because you will get most benefit by thinking these things through yourself.)

Comment: looking at it, looks like I need a tally count if I'm correct to keep track of the tally's

Comment: I need change the decrement of undo() to change from value to tally. I agree with you just keep telling if i'm getting closer

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things with the code:

- Your `setLimit()` method doesn't do what it's advertised to do.  It's not setting anything.  It's also only printing out, "Hey we exceeded the limit here!"  That doesn't stop a loop.
- You have no `break` in your looping structure.  That's the only way you can stop looping.

Your criteria for setting a limit seems arbitrary, but we can work with it.  Let's change the `setLimit()` method to an actual setter.  (I would also encourage you to change the field name from `value` to `limit` to avoid confusion.)

```
public void setLimit(int someLimit) {
    limit = someLimit;
}
```

Next, we have to specify in our loop to stop iterating when we've hit that limit.

```
for(int i = 0; i <=10; i++) {
    if(i == tally.getLimit()) {
        System.out.printf("Limit of %d exceeded\n", i);
        break;
    }
    tally.count();
    System.out.printf("After count %d, tally is %d\n", i,
                       tally.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Look at this code. This code sets value after being looped 7 times. check the condition `i > 7`. So, you would never get the line `After count 5, tally is 5 Limit of 5 exceeded`

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {

   if (i > 7) 
   {
   tally.setLimit(6);
   }
```

**2)** You don't have `setValue` defnied in `CounterExtended` class, which is required to set `value` variable.

```
public void setValue(int value)
{ 
this.value = value
}
```

Comment: @JDMshifter, public void setValue(int value){ this.value = value}

Answer (score 0):

finally figured it out, the directions in the book are not so clear. But thanks!

```
public class CounterExtended {
    private int value;
    private int tallyLimit = 5;

    /**
     * Gets the current value of this counter.
     * 
     * @return the current value
     */
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Advances the value of this counter by 1.
     */
    public void count() {
        if (value < tallyLimit) {
            value = value + 1;
        } else {
            System.out.printf("Limit of %d exceeded\n", tallyLimit);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Resets the value of this counter to 0.
     */
    public void reset() {
        value = 0;
    }
    /**
     * Sets limit on the tally 
     * 
     */
    public void setLimit(int maximum) {
        tallyLimit = maximum;
        ;
    }
    /**
     * Undos a button click or decrements the tally.
     */
    public void undo() {
        if (value != 0) {
            value--;
        }

    }
}
```